# How to rewrite the TCP destination port during the TCP connection on Windows?

Tags: windows, redirect, tcp, port

I have a client which is intended to connect to a server. For the client, the remote TCP port number is fixed(i.e. 102). I can NOT change it(while I can change the remote IP address). However, the TCP Port number the server is listening on is fixed as well(i.e. 1024) and I can NOT change it too. These two port numbers are different. I want to make the client connect to the server smoothly.

At the first, I had a idea that I setup a proxy listening on localhost:102 and the client connect to 127.0.0.1:102. Then this proxy redirect these TCP traffic to the real address RemoteServerIP:1024. But I found on my windows, there was already a process which is listening on 0.0.0.0:102 and I can NOT change its listening port. So this idea can NOT work.

Thank you very much.

Comment: So you can't do it. What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot do it on the same windows machine running client, why not try to do it on another (linux maybe) machine?